# QSslSocket errors

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt 4.8 on Windows 7 Ultimate x64, when I try to use `QNetworkAccessManager` to `post()` something over the network:

```
_net_acc_mgr.post(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(...)),
                  QByteArray(...));
```

I encounter the following run time errors:

```
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
content-type missing in HTTP POST, defaulting to application/octet-stream
```

I clearly remember the same code worked couple of years ago. But I forget which version of Qt I tried.

Is there anything else require to work with `QNetworkAccessManager` in Qt 4.8?

Comment: Hi! My answer solve your problem? If so check as "correct", if not tell me what is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The QT runs on *32bit*
- In *Windows 64bit* the folder *system32* does not have the *DLLs*
  required for *OpenSSL*, only there in *sysWOW64 folder*.
- To resolve this you will need to install the binary version of
  *OpenSSL 32*.

**Download compiled for Windows (Update link):**

http://slproweb.com/download/Win32OpenSSL_Light-1_0_1g.exe

> Note: During install select the option "The OpenSSL binaries (/bin) directory" (Probably `C:\OpenSSL-Win32`)

After install copy DLLs (from `C:\OpenSSL-32` or `%HOMEDRIVE%\OpenSSL-32`) for release/debug project folder:

- libeay32.dll
- libssl32.dll
- ssleay32.dll

---

Another option would be to use the *Mingw 64bit*, but do not know if this would be feasible with the *QT* (this case, if you can compile the application will run only on 64bit systems).

Comment: Putting third-party DLLs in System32 / SysWow64 causes "DLL Hell" (when different programs want to install slightly different versions with the same file name). Keep your DLLs in your program folder to avoid this.

Comment: @AndrewMedico For this reason I updated the answer. Notice that I said "After install copy DLLs for release / debug project folder". The part that I talked about "system32" and "sysWOW64" is to explain what causes the problem.